# Missing Arguments

Tags: python, list

---python

```
def insert_begining(self, data):
    nb = Node(data)
    nb.next = self.head
    self.head = nb
```

---

```
 def display(self):
     if self.head is None:
     print('The list is empty')
        else:
        temp = self.head
            while temp:
            print(temp.data, "-->", end = " " )
            temp = temp.next


L.insert_begining(23)

L.display()
```

Errors: missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'&
missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: What is your question about this error message?

Comment: if the first element is self that means that you need to define this function inside a class. Otherwise why do you put self?

Comment: @mkrieger1How to resolve this?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I am calling that function.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Currently, the code isn't indented correctly and wouldn't run at all.

Comment: Is this code part of class `L` (terrible name by the way)?

Answer (score 2):

The question should be explicit.  What you have here, if I'm to guess, is that you copied some code from a class and didn't then put it into its own new class.  Only functions that are members of a class require the 'self' parameter (which is handled automatically by the interpreter).  Otherwise, self just becomes another parameter in your list that needs to be specified by the caller.